# Splice removing option to click checkbox after first click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a checkbox that needs to be clicked on and off. However, within my function, the splice is only allowing for this to happen once as once a user selects the checkbox it removes it from the array. How can I make the checkbox toggle-able?

```
const [supplierAddress, setSupplierAddress] = useState([]);

const handleAddressCheck = item => {
  console.log(item);
  const itemIndex = supplierAddress.findIndex(supplierItem => supplierItem.id === item.id);
  if (itemIndex >= 0) {
    setSupplierAddress(supplierAddress.splice(itemIndex, 1));
  } else {
    setSupplierAddress(supplierAddress.concat([item]));
  }

};


{
  sfilteredSuppliers.map(row => (
    <TableRow key={row.id}>
      <TableCell scope="row">{row.name}</TableCell>
      <TableCell scope="row">{row.companyRegistrationNumber}</TableCell>
      <TableCell scope="row">{row.vatRegistrationNumber}</TableCell>
      <TableCell scope="row">{row.website}</TableCell>
      <TableCell scope="row">
        <Checkbox
          checked={supplier.find(supplierItem => supplierItem.id === row.id)}
          name="checked"
          color="primary"
          onChange={() => handleCheckChange(row)} />
      </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  ))
}
```

Comment: dont use mutations on state. splice mutates data and will change secretly without allowing fo rerenders.

Comment: 1. shouldn't `handleCheckChange` be `handleAddressCheck` ?
2. Shouldn't `supplier.find` be `supplierAddress.find` ?
3. `splice` returns the removed elements so using the result in `setSupplierAddress` looks to be the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is, [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) doesn't return the updated array (array after deleting the item), it returns the deleted item/items, also it will mutate the original array. So instead of using [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) better to use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Like this:

```
const handleAddressCheck = item => {
  const itemIndex = supplierAddress.findIndex(supplierItem => supplierItem.id === item.id);
  if (itemIndex >= 0) {

      // here
      setSupplierAddress(supplierAddress.filter(el => el.id != item.id));

  } else {
      setSupplierAddress(supplierAddress.concat([item]));
  }
};
```

Check this example:

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let index = 2;

let b = a.splice(index, 1);

// item will be removed from the array
console.log('a', a);

// b will be [3]
console.log('b', b);
```

Comment: Hey thankyou this has solved my problem, however if you could could you break down this line of code to me    setSupplierAddress(supplierAddress.filter(el => el.id != item.id)); what exactly is happening here?

Comment: sure, so if you break that line it will be: `let newArr = supplierAddress.filter(el => el.id != item.id);
setSupplierAddress(newArr);`, filter will return a new array after removing that particular item. also filter will not do the changes in original array, it will return new array without that item. That array we are passing to `setSupplierAddress` that will be new value of `supplierAddress`.